# Should I delete last 7 layers of VGG16 as I am going to use it as a pretrained model for a signature verification task?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

As far as I know, cnn's last layers identify objects as a whole, this is irrelevant to the dataset with signatures. Thus, I want to remove them and add additional layers on top of the model, freezing the VGG16 from training. How would the removal of layers potentially affect the model's performance, or should I just leave and delete only dense layers?

I need to add additional layers on top anyway for the school report about the effect of convolutional layers' configurations on the model's performance.

p.s my dataset is really small it contains nearly 700 samples, which is extremely small n i know that(i tried augmenting data)

I have a dataset with Chinese signatures, but I thought that it is better to train it separately//

I am not  proficient in this field and I started my acquaintance from deep learning, so pls correct me if you noticed any misconception in my explanation?/

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use VGG with include_top=False, weights='imagenet, and set pooling = max. This will instantiate the model with imagenet weights, the top classification layer is removed and the output of the VGG model is a flat vector you can feed directly into a dense layer. My typical code for this is shown below. In the final layer class_count is the number of classes in the training data.

```
base_model=tf.keras.applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights="imagenet",input_shape=img_shape, pooling='max') 
x=base_model.output
x=keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 )(x)
x = Dense(256, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(l = 0.016),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
                bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006) ,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(rate=.45, seed=123)(x)        
output=Dense(class_count, activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How would the removal of layers potentially affect the model's performance, or should I just leave and delete only dense layers?

This is hard to answer because what performance are you talking about? VGG16 originally were build to Imagenet problem with 1000 classes, so if you use it without any modifications probably won't work at all.

Now, if you are talking about transfer learning, so yes, the last dense layers could be replaced to classify your dataset, because the model created with cnn layers in VGG16 is a good pattern recognizer. The fully connected layers at the end work as a classifier for this patterns and you should replace it and train it again for your specific problem. VGG16 has 3 dense layers (FC1, FC2 and FC3) at end, keras only allow you to remove all three, so if you want replace just the last one, you will need to remove all three and rebuild the FC1 and FC2.

The key is what you are going to train after that, you could:

1. Use original weights (imagenet) in cnn layers and start you trainning from that, just finetunning with a small learning rate. A good choice when you dataset is similar to original and you have a good amount of it.
2. Use original weights (imagenet) in cnn layers, but freeze them, and just training the weights in the dense layers you replaced. A good choice when your dataset is small.
3. Don't use the original weights and retrain all the model. Usually not a good choice, because you will need to be an expert to tunning the parameters, tons of data and computacional power to make it work.